# Entity Framework 4.1 auto generate with DbContext when creating ADO.NET Entity Data Model

Tags: visual-studio-2010, entity-framework-4.1, dbcontext

I would like to work with DbContext instead of ObjectContext. I updated EF so now I have the DbContext, but I want to generate my strongly-typed context based on the DbContext and not the ObjectContext.  When I add new ADO.NET Entity Data Model, it is still based on the ObjectContext.  Is it not possible to have it base off of DbContext in Visual Studio 2010 with EF 4.1?

**UPDATE:**

Okay, I followed the directions in this [link](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2011/09/28/ef-4-2-model-amp-database-first-walkthrough.aspx) and was able to generate the DbContext template objects.  However, now it is saying there is ambiguity between the template entities and the entities in my .edmx file.  How do I resovle this?  Do I blow away the ones in the .edmx file?

Comment: Just spent a few minutes trying to figure this one out myself.  If you just add the DbContext generator directly from NuGet, it does *not* configure the edmx to stop using the ObjectContext generator.  Apparently, this is resolved in VS2012 where DbContext is the default. Added a tag to clarify that this is a VS2010 issue.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Okay, I got this to work by right-clicking in the .edmx diagram view and selecting 'Add Code Generation Item...' and then selecting 'EF 4.x DbContext Generator' from the options.  It worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

You can generate ObjectContext from existing edmx file, just go to the properties of edmx change "Code Generation Strategy" to Default then it automatically generate ObjectContext.